# I got a lv71 Legendary when I'm 72. What gives?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was under the impression that loot dropped from mobs was assigned either your current level or one level higher. Farmed Hunter Hellquist last night and got a 71 Bee. Is this a bug or am I just super unlucky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loot can be anywhere between two levels below and two levels above you. If you are max level, this means you have a 66% chance to get an item one or two levels below your own.

If you have DLC4 (Tiny Tina), I recommend farming Treeants instead in the blood pool in the Forest. They have the same chance to drop The Bee as HH, but there are far more of them.

Comment: Is there really a 66% chance? It always seemed to me at max level items have more chance to be my level than not

Comment: 66% chance of having an unusable item seems really high...

Comment: @Ben Brocka The chances are evenly distributed among the possibilities (33% chance for either on-level, 1 level lower or 2 levels lower), meaning that there's a 33% chance of a desirable outcome, and a 66% chance of a less-than-desirable outcome. And most items (especially Legendaries) don't really become unusable after just 1 level.